# Ubuntu 16.04lts 64bit just detected RAM 3.1gb of 8gb

Tags: 16.04, ram

My user have a laptop ACER Aspire E5-551 processor AMD A10-7300,
When i upgrade the RAM from 4GB(2x2GB) to 8GB(2x4GB) with brand, type, and speed are same,

The system just detected 3.1GB RAM checked by system monitor,
Check by lshw -c memory also just 3.1GB,
But when i check dmidecode --type 17, all ram detected, 8GB RAM 2x4GB,
Check on bios also got 8GB,
And check by live usb ubuntu 18.04lts 64bit also got 8GB,

Is there something that i can try to fix this issue ?

Please help,
Thank You,

Comment: PAE is a 32-bit only package. 64-bit Ubuntu doesn't need it. Please edit your question to include the complete output of the command `uname -a`

Comment: Can you update  your question with output from: `journalctl -xb |grep "Memory: "`

Comment: To edit your question so you can add more information to it, please click [edit]. Please do not respond with Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: thanks for support,
sorry the laptop is not mine, so i can't use it freely,
all that i know, it use ubuntu 16.04lts 64bit,
and the result of test that i have done,

i will edit this question again when i can use the laptop,